# Stored procedure in Postgres not returning values

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I am rather new to Postgres, and have created a simple table:

```
create table aeroplanes 
(
    plane_id int generated by default as identity,
    name varchar(100) not null,
    speed INTEGER not null,
    primary key(plane_id)
);

insert into aeroplanes (name, speed)
values ('saab', 2500);

insert into aeroplanes (name, speed)
values ('boeing', 800);
```

My stored procedure is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE search_airplane_name(name_param varchar)
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
SELECT * FROM aeroplanes
WHERE name = name_param;
$$;
```

But when calling the procedure with the following:

```
CALL search_airplane_name('saab');
```

In pgadmin in messages I get the following:

> Query returned successfully

but I can't see any results, and when I click the data output tab, it says:

> No data output

but I can't see any output, and if I click on

Comment: If you run the `SELECT` statement separately outside of the procedure do you get the expected result? Possibly the rows did not get committed to the table when inserted?

Comment: if I run a select * from aeroplanes to check if the tables has two rows and if 'saab' is in the name colum, and the call the procedure,  I get the same response, that the query ran successfully but no data output.

Comment: You want a FUNCTION instead of a PROCEDURE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stored procedures do not have to return anything, and only return a single row when using `INOUT` parameters.

So you need a `function` for that :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION search_airplane_name(name_param varchar)
returns setof aeroplanes 
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT * FROM aeroplanes
WHERE name = name_param;
$$;
```

Then run :

```
SELECT * FROM search_airplane_name('saab');
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/rDjIJuBf)

Comment: Yes, I already created a function and that worked, but I need to understand why I cant use a stored procedure for this and why functions is better suited. Is it so that stored procedures are better suited for transaction or data manipulation type of issues? And functions better for pure sql query type of issues in Postgres? I wonder because I have used stored procedure in msSQL for this type.

Comment: Have a look here : https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/262662/267212